# Is there any example of a endomorphism of a Lie group that has recurrent points with non-compact orbit closure?

Tags: lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems

Is there any example of a continuous endomorphism of a Lie group that has recurrent points with non-compact orbit closure?

Comment: You probably want $G$ connected? In general, we can reduce to the case when $G/G^0$ is cyclic and the endomorphism induces the identity on $G/G^0$, but it's not clear we can reduce to $G$ connected.

Comment: If there's an example, there an example given by an automorphism. It's based on the fact that every endomorphism of a connected Lie group with dense image is an automorphism. So if $f:G\to G$ is a counterexample with recurrent point $g$, we see that $g\in H=\bigcap_n\mathrm{ closure}(f^n(G))$ and $f$ induces an automorphism of $H$.

Comment: Yes I am more interested in the case where $G$ is connected. The map $f(z) = z^2$ is a surjective endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}^*$ or of $S^1$, but it is not an automorphism, or I am missing something?

Comment: Oh, yes you're right. So, I mean, we can reduce to the case of an endomorphism that is a self-covering (surjective with discrete kernel, actually necessarily finite), based on the fact that an endomorphism with dense image always has this form.

Comment: @Mauro: I seek clarification. Suppose  $f$ is the endomorphism with a recurrent point $p$. Does it mean there exists an integer $m$ such that $f^m(p)=p$? Then the orbit of $p$ is finite. If you are asking if $some$ $other$ orbit of $f$ is non-compact, of course there are examples

Comment: @Venkataramana: A point $p$ is a recurrent of $f$ if there is a sequence $n_k \to \infty$ such that $f^{n_k}(p) \to p$.

Comment: If $G$ is semisimple and linear we can assume that $f$ is surjective. In fact, there is an integer $m$ such that $f$ restricted to $H = f^m(G)$ is surjective and $H$ is semisimple and thus closed, since $G$ is linear.

Comment: Assuming that $G$ is linear semisimple and $f$ surjective, every recurrent point of $f$ has compact orbit closure. In fact, there is an integer $n$ such that $f^n$ is an inner automorphism and thus a restriction to $G$ of a linear map and $G$ is a closed subset. The claim follows since the orbit closure of every recurrent point of a linear map is a torus.

Comment: @Mauro: thanks. Will have to think about non-(linear semi-simple) case, then

Comment: @YCor: If $G$ is solvable and $T$ is the maximal torus in its center, then $G/T$ is solvable and simply-connected and an endomorphism $f$ induces a endomorphism $\phi$ on $G/T$. Thus there exists a recurrent point of $f$ with a non-compact orbit closure if and only if there exists a recurrent point of $\phi$ with a non-compact orbit closure. Hence, if $G$ is solvable, we can assume that $G$ is simply-connected.

Comment: @YCor: If $G$ is nilpotent, then every recurrent point of $f$ has compact orbit closure. In fact, this follows by the above remark and the fact that if $G$ is nilpotent and simply-connected, then $f$ is conjugated to a linear map and thus every recurrent point of $f$ has compact orbit closure.

Comment: Dear @YCor, it is really immediate that a surjective endomorphism of a Lie group is a self-covering map. But why is it necessarily finite? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is not what I said. I said that a endomorphism with dense image is a self-covering map (i.e., it's surjective). It's not so immediate (there are non-surjective homomorphisms with dense images between connected Lie groups, e.g. a line into a torus).

Comment: @YCor: Yes, indeed you had made a stronger claim. But I would like to know if it is easy to show that a surjective endomorphism of a Lie group is a finite self-covering map. If not, could you give me some reference? Thank you very much!

Comment: If $f:G\to G$ is a self-covering with kernel $Z$, we have $G\simeq G/Z$, inducing a group isomorphism $\pi_1(G)\simeq\pi_1(G/Z)$. Let $G'$ be the universal cover and $Z'$ the inverse image of $Z$, and $K\subset Z'$ the kernel of $G'\to G$, so $Z'/K\simeq Z$. Then $\pi_1(G)\simeq K$ and $\pi_1(G/Z)\simeq Z'$. Hence $K\simeq Z'$. Since $Z'$ is a finitely generated abelian group and $K$ a subgroup, we deduce that $K$ has finite index in $Z'$. So $Z\simeq Z'/K$ is finite.